# Corte de papel (acionar guilhotina) na impressora Bematech MP-4200 TH

Tags: java, impressora

Como fazer a impressora Bematech MP-4200 TH (não-fiscal) cortar o papel ao final da impressão em uma aplicação Java?

Answer (score 5):

Documentando a solução que encontrei.

**Ressalvas:** 1.: Evite misturar impressão via DLL com via Spooler, pode causar falhas de comunicação e gerar caracteres espúrios na impressão. 2.: a DLL (ou minha instalação) tem um bug, o comando FormataTX não aceita o tipo de letra 3 (Elite), ignora e imprime com letra 2 (normal) ou 1 (condensado).

- Para a impressora do modelo em questão, que é uma não-fiscal,  [a forma de interagir com Java de acordo com a Bematech é via JNA](http://partners.bematech.com.br/suporte-e-recursos/faq?action=ViewPosts&fid=133&tid=16565&topic=Linguagem-de-Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-JAVA-(BEMATECH-MP-4200-TH)). (Obs.: [não é a única](http://partners.bematech.com.br/bemacast/Paginas/post.aspx?idPost=5806), mas é a que funcionou). Existe um exemplo que usa JNI e o pacote `Bematech.jar`, mas ele é para impressoras fiscais, portanto não funciona na MP-4200 TH. Existem relatos da impressora funcionar no Java aceitando comandos ESC/POS se for instalada com Driver Genérico, mas comigo não deu certo, então eu desisti dessa abordagem.
- Esta resposta é para Windows 7 64 bits, mas o JDK pode ser 64 ou 32 bits, só terá que usar a DLL correta para o seu caso ([mp2032](http://partners.bematech.com.br/suporte-e-recursos/paginas/DetalhesDownload.aspx?ID=90) ou [mp2064](http://partners.bematech.com.br/suporte-e-recursos/paginas/DetalhesDownload.aspx?ID=92)).
- Se estiver usando a versão 32 bits, os arquivos *mp2032.dll*, *mp2032.ini*, *SiUSBXp.dll* contidos no pacote mp2032 deverão ser copiados para a pasta-raiz da aplicação Java (retornada por `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"))`). Deve dar certo também se copiar para *C:\Windows\System32*, mas eu não fiz o teste.
- Se estiver usando a versão 64 bits, os arquivos *mp2064.dll*, *mp2064.ini*, *SiUSBXp.dll* contidos no pacote mp2064 deverão ser copiados para o mesmo local dito acima.
- Se quiser saber mais sobre os arquivos *.ini*, veja [este artigo](http://partners.bematech.com.br/bemacast/Paginas/post.aspx?title=edicao-203---novo-arquivo-de-configuracao-da-dll-mp203264&idPost=6243).
- Baixe o [Exemplo JNA](http://partners.bematech.com.br/suporte-e-recursos/paginas/DetalhesDownload.aspx?ID=211) da Bematech e importe no Eclipse (ou na IDE de sua preferência).
- Se estiver usando a versão 64 bits, altere a parte do código que diz "mp2032" para "mp2064". Ou então para fazer o código suportar as duas versões acrescente o seguinte à interface `BematechNFiscal.java`:

  ```
  public static final boolean IS_64_BIT_JVM =
      "64".equals(System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model"));
  public static final BematechNFiscal INSTANCE =
      (BematechNFiscal) Native.loadLibrary(IS_64_BIT_JVM ?
      "mp2064" : "mp2032", BematechNFiscal.class);
  ```

Adicione à interface `BematechNFiscal.java` a seguinte linha:

```
public int AcionaGuilhotina(int tipoDeCorte);
```

Pode agora editar a classe `Principal.java` e chamar o `AcionaGuilhotina(1)` para corte total ou `AcionaGuilhotina(0)` para corte parcial.

Essa é a orientação para usar uma impressora previamente instalada na máquina. Para instalar a impressora é preciso instalar o driver que vem junto com o pacote mp2032 ou mp2064 e também com instruções de instalação (um arquivo PDF). Siga essas instruções para instalar o driver (versão atual 3.4.0.0). Atenção que entre desinstalações e instalações tem que reiniciar a máquina.

Para a impressora ser adicionada à lista de impressoras do sistema operacional, é preciso instalar o Spooler Driver. Ele vem junto com os drivers da impressora sob o nome *Bematech MP4200 TH - Driver Win BemaSetup MP4K x64 V4.2.0.exe*.

Esse último driver eu vou deixar a seu cargo achar e baixar, ele vem em um pacote de outros 4 ou 5 drivers incluindo para Linux. Espero que alguma  boa alma venha aqui e complete a informação fornecendo o link.

Dica: [Este é o site de downloads da Bematech](http://partners.bematech.com.br/suporte-e-recursos/downloads).